# PostGIS/PostgreSQL - ERROR: must be owner of type spheroid

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, postgis

Hope you are well.

I am trying to move a PostGIS data table from one server to another. I have installed postgresql on the target machine, configured it to allow sensible authentication (username/password). I have also used yum to install the postgis2_91 package (including debuginfo, devel, docs and utils).

When i initially tried to restore the sql dump to the target server i got a load of errors, i put this down to postgis not being installed as it was complaining about the "geometry" data type.

I believe i need to follow these instructions (from spatially enable database) http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21CentOS6pgdg however, when i tried to run the command below I got an error saying "ERROR: must be owner of the spheroid", this is while I'm logged in as the "postgres" user which I believe has full permissions?

```
 CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Edit - I managed to fix this by completely removing postgres and postgis, then tried the procedure again and it worked. No idea why it didn't work but it is now resolved.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Sounds like your dump restored a (partial?) copy of an old PostGIS from before extensions, and you ran the restore as a different user ID.

Comment: I think it is an issue with templates. See http://linfiniti.com/2011/12/upgrade-database-postgis-2/